# Firefox/Chrome/LAMP: UTF-8 - invalid characters

Tags: php, html, firefox, google-chrome, utf-8

I tried to convert a website to UTF-8. For that, I converted the PHP files to UTF-8, added a `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`, added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to the HTML-header, converted the mysql table-content to utf-8 (ALTER ...) and also set the MySQL-connection encoding to utf-8.

Now, everyhting seems to be fine, but sometimes IE8, Firefox and Chrome shows � instead of german umlauts. IE9 doesn't show this issue at all.

After refreshing, the issue is resolved, but after a while or several refreshes the � shows up again,....

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you double-check that the served encoding is really UTF-8? You can do that in Firefox by right-clicking on the page, and then “View Page Info”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, got it!

the issue was, that the mysql client encoding was changed by an embedded Ad-Server (OpenX).

Now, I set the charset back to UTF-8 after "view_local" was executed and everything seems to be fine now!

Thank you for your support which helped me to find the root cause of this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Often such behaviour is caused by IE's quirks mode. If your page is not valid HTML, the browser can fall back to the quirksmode, you can check this pressing F12 to show the developer toolbar.

If the shown mode is the quirksmode, you can solve your problem by writing valid HTML. There are offline and [online HTML Validators](http://validator.w3.org/) available.

If the shown mode matches your browser, then you can use the [W3-checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) to find problems with your pages encoding.

Edit:

Also make sure you set the encoding of the connection object before you use it. You wrote that you set the MySQL-connection to utf-8, but you didn't write how you did it.

```
// tells the mysqli connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$db->set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: The problem not only occurs in IE.

Comment: @looper - You are right i missed it, but in this case we can use the mentioned W3-checker, it can discover encoding problems.